# Return object from array with highest value

Tags: powershell

I want to return an object from an array who's property has the highest value. Currently I am doing the following

```
Get-VM | Sort-Object -Property ProvisionedSpaceGB | Select-Object -Last 1
```

This works but is inefficient. I don't need the entire array sorted, I just need the object with largest value. Ideally I would use something like

```
Get-VM | Measure-Object -Property ProvisionedSpaceGB -Maximum
```

but this only returns the value of the object property, not the entire object. Is there a way to have measure-object return the base object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not directly.  `Measure-Object` is intended to be an easy way to grab such values, not their input objects.  You *could* get the maximum from Measure-Object and then compare against the array, but it takes a few steps:

```
$array = Get-VM
$max = ($array | measure-object -Property ProvisionedSpaceGB -maximum).maximum
$array | ? { $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB -eq $max}
```

You could also forgo Measure-Object entirely and iterate through the set, replacing the maximum and output as you go.

```
$max = 0
$array | Foreach-Object 
{ 
    if($max -le $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB)
    { 
        $output = $_ 
        $max = $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB
    } 
}
$output
```

This is a little dirtier so as to always return a single value.  It would need a minor adjustment if you were to reuse it in a case where there may be multiple values that have the same maximum (filesize lengths when using Get-ChildItem, for example).  It will replace `$output` with the latter iterate in a case where two or more objects have the same value for `ProvisionedSpaceGB`. You could turn `$output` into a collection easily enough to fix that.

I prefer the former solution myself, but I wanted to offer a different way to think about the problem.

Comment: If you re-wrote

`$array | ? { $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB -eq $max}`

as
`@($array | ? { $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB -eq $max})[0]`

that might return a single value for you, but as Hyper Anthony noted, not always be the one you wanted.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this:

```
$array = Get-VM | Sort-Object  -Property ProvisionedSpaceGB -Descending
$array[0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is doing, only in one line.