# powershell value comparison in array

Tags: arrays, comparison

let's say that I have an array with differents values
example : `$myarray = @(1,2,35,4,5,6)`

I simply want to have the greater value of `$myarray`; in the example the answer will be `35`.
I can't find if there is a cmdlet returning the greater value of an array.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another similar question with an answer:
[Return object from array with highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966533/return-object-from-array-with-highest-value)

And here's an example that should help as well:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/14/powertip-find-the-largest-number-in-a-powershell-array.aspx

> PS C:> $a = [array]1,2,5,6,3,2,9,1
>
> PS C:> $a | measure -Maximum
>
> Count    : 8
>
> Average  :
>
> Sum      :
>
> Maximum  : 9
>
> Minimum  :
>
> Property :

Comment: Happy to help! Please be so kind to vote up my answer and accept it, if you find it helpful. Thank you ! :)